# If $\|A\| \leq 1$ and $A \geq 0$, then $\|I - A\| \leq 1$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ be a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space such that $A \geq 0$. I would like to show that if $\|A\| \leq 1$ then $\|I - A\| \leq 1$, where the norms are the operator norms.

By definition we have that
$$\|I- A\| = \sup_{\|\varphi\| = 1} |\langle(I-A)\varphi, \varphi \rangle|.$$
Here I am taking the inner product to be linear in the second argument. Informally, I can see why this is true since
$$|\langle(I-A)\varphi, \varphi \rangle| = |\overline{\langle \varphi, (I-A)\varphi \rangle}| = |\langle(I-A)\varphi, \varphi \rangle| = | \langle \varphi, \varphi\rangle - \langle \varphi, A \varphi \rangle|.$$
Since the supremum is taken over all $\|\varphi\| = 1$, my informal calculation continues as
$$ = | 1 - \langle \varphi, A \varphi \rangle|.$$
Since $A$ is assumed to be positive and hence self-adjoint, and $\| A \| \leq 1$, the above seems to lead to the desired result.

There are a few problems with my calculations so I am not sure if this is the right path. For example, I am taking the supremum of each value separately without breaking up the absolute value.

How can I make this argument rigorous, assuming it is correct?

Comment: 'By definition, we have that...' This is not how you define the norm of an operator.

Comment: @geetha290krm You are right, I did not notice that. The textbook I am following says "Since $\|I- A\| = \sup_{\|\varphi\| = 1} |\langle(I-A)\varphi, \varphi \rangle| \ldots$", so I thought this was a consequence of the definition of the operator norm without checking. Where does this follow from?

Comment: The formula $$   \left\Vert A\right\Vert =\sup_{\left\Vert x\right\Vert =1}\left|\left\langle Ax,x\right\rangle \right| $$ is true in Hilbert spaces whenever the operator is Hermitian. I believe that since the operator is nonnegative it should follow it is also self adjoint, and Hermitian in particular.

Comment: @YehonathanS. Thank you for your comment. I took a look at my textbook and that is listed as an exercise, which explains why I had not seen that before.

Comment: As $\|A\|\le 1$ we get $1-\langle A\varphi,\varphi\rangle \ge 0$ for $\|\varphi\|=1,$ so the absolute value can be omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A\geq 0$ and $\|A\|\leq 1$, then for any $\varphi$ such that $\|\varphi\|=1$
$$
0\leq \langle \varphi, A\varphi\rangle \leq \|A\|\, \|\varphi\|^2 \leq 1
$$
so $0\leq A\leq I$, which implies that $0\leq I-A \leq I$, and so
$$
0\leq \langle\varphi,(I-A)\varphi\rangle \leq 1.
$$